# TYPO3 form - select an option from select box with get parameter

Tags: forms, select, parameters, typo3

I'm trying to have a TYPO3 request form that is called from a simple link with a parameter, e.g.

```html
  <a href="contact/inquiry/?tx_form[Product-line]=14">request</a>
```

The TYPO3 form has a select box with some options:

```html
<select id="field-10" name="tx_form[Product-line]">
        <option value="11">Product 1</option>
        <option value="12">Product 2</option>
        <option value="13">Product 3</option>
      </select>
```

How can I preselect the option with a get parameter here?

Comment: It depends on how you create the select field. Is it fluid and extbase? Or pure HTML? Please tell us how the select is generated.

Comment: it is created with form plugin:
60 = SELECT
60 {
 name = Product line
 label {
  value = Please select the product line your request belongs to
 }
 10 = OPTION
 10 {
  data = Product 1
 }
 20 = OPTION
 20 {
  data = Product 2
 }
 30 = OPTION
 30 {
  data = Product 3
 }
 40 = OPTION
 40 {
  data = Product 4
 }
}

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using? 6 or 7?